# Can the word “personnel” ever be singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage, uncountable-nouns

Can *personnel* be used in reference to a single person?  See the example below:

> Testing must take place by a qualified personnel other than the requestor.

Comment: As the [dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/personnel) states, _personnel_ is a _plural noun_. So, no. Such questions are deemed to be _general reference_ and I'm marking it to be closed as such.

Comment: But the sentence would be acceptable without _a_, even if there was only every going to be one tester.

Comment: Thank you, Colin.  That was the major question here.  I realize it was quite simple.  Evidently, simplistic questions are frowned upon here.  Research before submitting this question turned up various discussions that had no real resolution.  Interesting that although it is defined as a plural noun, it can be a single tester?

Comment: (Maybe simple answers are frowned upon here, too.) Would it work to simply say, "Testing must take place by a qualified person?" That would solve the single tester/plural personnel conundrum. If you must keep "personnel," then keep the plural verb even if you are thinking of a single tester, as in, "All personnel test in 30 minute intervals."

Comment: Likely a **regionalism**, maybe not. I have seen scores of instances with the purportedly incorrect singular use of *personnel*: "An unusual cause of scapular winging following trauma in **an army personnel** ."; "An army personnel inspects ... a garment factory after a devastating fire ..."; "The photograph ... showing **a police personnel** being punished by his senior officer,..."; "A police personnel conducting a search of a visitor"; "... passengers watch a police personnel talking over a megaphone ... "; Voting to re-open.

Comment: The question does not mention AmE then why the AmE tag? Will the OP and the Ed clarify?

Comment: @aeternus828: Testing doesn't normally "**take place by**" anybody. The standard phrasing is *"Testing [must be undertaken by qualified personnel](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22must+be+undertaken+by+qualified+personnel%22&oq=%22must+be+undertaken+by+qualified+personnel%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.1745&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)"*.

Answer (score 2):

No, as *personnel* is plural.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/personnel) says

1. a body of persons employed in an organization or place of work.
2. ( used with a plural verb ) persons: All personnel are being given the day off.

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter can add a comment explaining what is wrong ?

Comment: @jwpat7 *wrong* with the answer or *wrong* with the down voter? Could be the later.

Comment: @Kris, could be!  That would be an interesting explanation.